# Is there a Haskell Time Typeclass

Tags: haskell

I want to build a function with type signature `Time t => t -> Bool`. When looking at the documentation of [Data.Time](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.2/html/libraries/time-1.2.0.3/Data-Time.html) there are several different types that work on time, such as: `UTCTime`, `LocalTime`, and `ZonedTime`, but I find no typeclass that unifies them. Is there any such one or should I treat time just as a `Num`? (i.e. a continuum)

Comment: Could you clarify what operations you want from this typeclass?

Comment: Arithmetic functions for comparison, addition, and subtraction.

Comment: I'd just use `Num` and `Ord`. You could always create your own `Time` typeclass if you think it would help.

Comment: Addition and subtraction are not really possible for LocalTime because it doesn't know when daylight saving time starts and ends. You could define something like `addTime timeZone t1 t2`, or just convert everything to UTC.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The vector-space package has a [affine space typeclass](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector-space/0.7.2/doc/html/Data-AffineSpace.html).

`Diff p` is here the time duration type (which should be an instance of `VectorSpace`), and `p` is the time point type. You'll need an extra `Ord` instance for comparisons.

This provides you with linear interpolation between time points for free.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such type class in the standard time library, but it is possible to implement one by yourself.

However, usually you should construct your program logic in such a way that `UTCTime` is used for all time-based calculations (and this is not Haskell-specific). `LocalTime` and `ZonedTime` should just be used to convert back and forth between UTC and a presentation that is showed to the user or for data that comes from external sources. This is probably the reason there are no ready-made functions for calculating time-diffs and time additions for local and zoned time types.

Answer (score 2):

Time is slightly strange.

Time can refer to *a specific instant in time* (e.g., 09:27 AM, 14 Feb 1821 AD), or *a duration of time* (e.g., 6 minutes).

It makes sense to add and subtract durations. It doesn't really make sense to find the sum of two instants in time; what would this represent? Adding a duration to an instant would give you another instant; that makes sense. And subtracting one instance from another ought to give you the duration between them.

In summary, temporal arithmetic is not as simple as you might imagine.

Now, what the `time` package provides? I have no idea. It sounds like all the times you mentioned are instants in time, not time durations...

Comment: Yep, this is called an *Affine Space*. Vectors are durations, points are time instants.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [HasTime](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/time-lens/0.3/doc/html/Data-Time-Lens.html#t%3aHasTime) class in the [time-lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-lens) package.

It gives you (both read and write) access to the `TimeOfDay` component of all those structures. So, if you implement your function for `TimeOfDay`, it can be easily generalised to `LocalTime`, `ZonedTime` and `UTCTime`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation (http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.2/html/libraries/time-1.2.0.3/Data-Time-Format.html), all of UTCTime, ZonedTime and LocalTime are instances of the typeclasses FormatTime and ParseTime. They should be what you are looking for.

Comment: Hmm, if I understand them correctly they do not provide arithmetics on time, just parsing to/from strings.